# how to capture output in vector form instead of printing it in C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have a function within a large project of the form given below (func is called 5 times within the call hierarchy in some Abc class) :

```
 void Test::func(std::string c)
 {
       cout<<c;
 }
```

The function func is called by some functions in a large hierarchy. But all that the function func does is printing a string. Now instead of printing the string I want to store its output somewhere(in vector form) so that I may use it later in the program at the point where the hierarchy of func begins. I am completely clueless as to how should I capture this output instead of printing it. CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP.

Edit: I don't want to return the value from the function...because if I do so...the entire call hierarchy will get disturbed...is there some other way out instead of returning.

I want to define my own data structure whereby I can store it...but I am not getting how??

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
class Test
{
    std::stringstream accum;

    void func(std::string);
};

void Test::func(std::string c)
{
    accum << c;
}
```

or

```
class Test
{
    std::vector<std::string> accum;

    void func(std::string);
};

void Test::func(std::string c)
{
    accum.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a stream solution but use std::stringstream.  strstream is deprecated

Comment: @AndrewG: Thanks for that, I can't ever remember which one is the new one.